# How can I start / stop a request stream with node.js?

Tags: node.js, request

I have

```
return request({
  method: "POST",
  url: response.stream.url,
  json: true,
  forever: true,
  body: {
    sessionid: response.stream.sessionid,
    symbols: symbolParams
  }
}).on("data", onData)
```

That gives me data whenever it comes through. But what if I want to STOP listening on that stream, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener

```
const req = request({
    method: "POST",
    url: response.stream.url,
    json: true,
    forever: true,
    body: {
        sessionid: response.stream.sessionid,
        symbols: symbolParams
    }
}).on("data", onData);
...
req.removeEventListener('data', onData);
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems to implement Readable Stream interface, so pause() and resume() work.

```
const request = require('request');
const req = request('http://google.com')
  .on('data', data => { 
      console.log(data);  
      req.pause(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also abort it:

```
var req = request('http://google.com')...
...
req.abort();
```